# Get values from a string using a format SWIFT

Tags: swift

I started off with this:

I wanted to format sentences using a specific string

```
let formatter = "%@ is friend of %@"
let you = "you"
let me = "me"
let reply = String(format: formatter, you, me)
```

This works fine. It prints **You is friend of me**

Now I want the opposite of this i.e.

if I have a string like this **You is friend of me** I want to get the values out of this string using the formatter `"%@ is friend of %@"` so that it gives out array of values as( "you" "me")

Any suggestion is helpful

Comment: It can be done by using Regular Expressions

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit complicated but you can try using Regular Expression.

```
let reply = "You is friend of me"
let format = "%@ is friend of %@"

var result: [String] = []

let pattern = NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: format)
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "%@", with: "(.*)")
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^" + pattern + "$")
if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: reply, range: NSRange(0..<reply.utf16.count)), match.numberOfRanges > 0 {
    for i in 1..<match.numberOfRanges {
        result.append(String(reply[Range(match.range(at: i), in: reply)!]))
    }
} else {
    print("format does not match")
}

print(result) //->["You", "me"]
```

Please try this code for some different format and the result text generated with the format.

Comment: @rmaddy, have you tried my code with actual `format` and `reply`?

Comment: Now that I look closer, I see the use of `escapedPattern`. I missed that. Never mind. :)

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks for confirmation. My code may generate wrong results, when matching can be ambiguous. I may be missing some other cases. Any suggestion is and will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
let str = yourString.replacingOccurrences(of: " is friend of ", with: ",")
let arr = str.components(separatedBy: ",")
print("first:- \(arr[0]) , second:- \(arr[1])")
```